# error: linker `link.exe` not found while trying to compile "Hello world"

Tags: rust, rustrover

I just downloaded RustRover for Windows 10 from JetBrains and I'm trying to run a simple "Hello world" program

```rust
fn main() {
    println!("Hello, world!");
}
```

But everytime I run it I'm getting the error

```
error: linker `link.exe` not found
```

What am I supposed to do to fix this error?

Comment: You should report this as feedback since RustRover is still in development. I know the MSVC toolchain for Rust on Windows requires the VS C++ build tools installed to get the linker: see [here](https://rust-lang.github.io/rustup/installation/windows-msvc.html). But I figure that *should* be handled for you by the RustRover installation since I see nothing about doing anything extra on their [install instructions](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/rust/installation-guide.html).

Comment: Looks like it is a known issue [RUST-11754](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/RUST-11754). Try installing VS C++ build tools before installing RustRover

Comment: You can run Rust on Windows without VS C++ installation using the `stable-x86_64-pc-windows-gnu` target, in some conditions though. https://github.com/rust-lang/rustup/issues/3358